# Spring sidecar application failing to discover the Eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

In order to integrate non-JVM applications to a microservice-based application, I am using the `Spring Boot` implmentation of Netflix `Sidecar` concept. I have looked at several examples and tried to learn from them including the official [spring documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__polyglot_support_with_sidecar.html). Unfortunately, the sidecar application cannot discover the `Eureka` server. The following error is thrown after I run the application:

```
DiscoveryClient_VISITS-SIDECAR/localhost:visits-sidecar:0 - registration failed There is no known eureka server; cluster server list is empty
```

Here the main class of the sidecar application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSidecar

public class VisitsSidecarApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(VisitsSidecarApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

The necessary dependencies are also included in the `pom`. I will appreciate any pointers as to where I am getting things wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have realized my mistake, my application.yml file was mis-configured hence the eureka server endpoint was incorrect. The `defaultZone` value was `localhost:8761` instead of `http://localhost:8761/eureka/`. Immediately I changed it the server was discovered by the sidecar application. Here is the correctly configured `application.yml` file:

```
server:
port: 9100
spring:
    application:
      name: vets-sidecar
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
sidecar:
  port: 9102
  health-uri: http://localhost:${sidecar.port}/health
```